# How can I arrange a dynamic list of divs into 2 columns

Tags: html, css, angular

have a div container which is a bag for drag and drop using dragula.

I also have a list of divs I want to arrange within this container in 2 columns - but ideally it shall look like a table, so 2 divs beside each other shall end up with the same size. Also the list of divs can vary - another div may be dropped into the dragula container or removed.

I tried this many ways - tried with floats, with divs using table classes, ... nothing worked so far. Btw - I am using Angular.

Any ideas?

To make it a little bit more complex - if the browser window falls below a certian size the display shall change to 1 column.

Adding a piece of code which doesnt work:

```
    <div [dragula]='"bag-fields"'[dragulaModel]="layout.sections[i].fields" style="min-height: 20px" style="width: 100%; display: flex">
        <div *ngFor="let field of section.fields" style="flex: 1; width 50%">
           <div atx-label class="labelCol" [field]="field" style="width: 50%"></div>
           <div atx-field class="dataCol" [field]="field" [layoutMode]="true" [editable]="false" style="width: 50%"></div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Rgds
Michael

Comment: CSS `flexbox` addresses such scenarios where it is impractical to use `float`s. Just ensure that the container `div` has style `display: flex;` and add CSS to rule rule to make every direct child of the container `flex`. If, for instance, your container div has class `container` use `.container > div { flex: 1; }`. For responsiveness once browser window resizes use CSS media query to define styles for various screen sizes

Comment: Yes, flexbox is a promising option.  And since you're using angular, you can add an "if" statement to your rendering that adds a new row after every other record.

Comment: Hi - I added my piece of code into my intial question. I used flexbox now - as described above but it doesnt work. Also not sure how I can add a new row every other record as recommended too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not completly sure if i understand you correctly but are you looking for something like this one:

```css
.bag-fields {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.bag-field {
  background-color: #ddd;
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-clip:content-box;
}

/* to make it 1 column on certain viewport width */
@media (max-width: 600px)  {
  .bag-field {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/* for testing purpose */
.bag-field:nth-child(3n) {
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bag-fields">
  <div class="bag-field">
    <div class="col labelCol"></div>
    <div class="col dataCol"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bag-field">
    <div class="col labelCol"></div>
    <div class="col dataCol"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bag-field">
    <div class="col labelCol"></div>
    <div class="col dataCol"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bag-field">
    <div class="col labelCol"></div>
    <div class="col dataCol"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bag-field">
    <div class="col labelCol"></div>
    <div class="col dataCol"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It uses `display: flex` and `flex-wrap` on the container to arrange the divs in columns. Then the div width is set to 50% of the containers width to make it a 2 column list. The height of the divs can be variable and will always be the same height per row.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I am almost there with your recommendations! I now get 2 columns. I noticed I missed used ';' instead of ':' for the width of the divs.

But there is still one problem - the div with labelCol is now above the dataCol div and not beside each other (despite I used float: left for the labelCol). 

Maybe the reason because the bag-fields again is in a div whicht is a table row since I have multiple bags?

Comment: I found the missing piece - another typo and thanks to your recommendation it works now!